# Is possible to use an Android Animator to animate a DialogFragment entry?

Tags: android, android-animation, objectanimator

I have a `DialogFragment` which I `show()` when the user clicks a button on my App.

I would like to set an animation to make a Z-axix rotation on the `DialogFragment` when it launches (i.e. a 3d card flip animation).

I have succesfully used the `windowAnimationStyle` and the following style to do simple animations (using the View Animation framework) when the `DialogFragment` is shown:

```
<style name="windowAnimationCardFlip" parent="@android:style/Animation.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/card_flip_left_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/card_flip_left_out</item>
 </style>
```

The problem is that the View Animation framework is (to the best of my knowledge), quite limited, and the only rotation that I'm able to do (on xml, at least) is a 2D XY rotation (I want a "3D" z axis rotation).

I tried to use the Property Animation framework (specifically an Object Animator, written in XML), but, while I'm able to achieve the effect when loading simple `Fragments` as described in the [official android tutorials](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html), when I try to apply that XML `ObjectAnimator` to the `windowEnterAnimation` attribute, nothing happens.

I would like to know, then, what could be happening? Is it possible to use an ObjectAnimator to animate the windowEntry event? If not, are there other solutions?

Comment: Have you tried making a custom animation? (class extending from animation and overriding the applytransformation, with this approach you can use de z axis to do transformations)

Comment: No, I haven't. Could you please give me some pointers?

Comment: I will give you some example code of an CustomAnimation extending from Animation. The effect there is a rotation over the Z-axis

Comment: also check out these video's of Chet Haase, He works on the graphics animation engine of the Android framework. These video's were released just yesterday: http://graphics-geek.blogspot.be/2013/01/devbytes-short-focused-android-tutorials.html