# how can I flip an android dialog on click?

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I have an android dialog

I saw this [tutorial](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/add-custom-transitions-to-android-alert-dialogs/) for swiping a dialog in and out.

how can I filp a dialog when the user clicks on the dialog.

I want to actually show the user two dialog with different content and trasit with flip between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [code from google](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) or combine it's xml if it works, saw also good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402382/is-possible-to-use-an-android-animator-to-animate-a-dialogfragment-entry)